# NSData dataWithContentsOfUrl: loads outdated data

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata

In my app I load some static JSON string from some server.

Every now and then the JSON file is updated and then I want the app to reload the data.

Now, that I updated the file on the server the app does not reflect the change. If I take the URL to that file from the app's code and copy it into a browser and fetch the file there, I clearly see the updates. But when I run the app and log the json string to the debug console, then I clearly see an outdated version of the file's content.

Is there any caching involved? Can I force the iOS to actually reload it?

This is how I load it now:

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:[DOWNLOAD_URL stringByAppendingString:DOWNLOAD_FILE]];
NSError * error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];

NSLog(@"JSON: %@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[jsonData bytes]]);
```

The option `NSDataReadingUncached` should prevent the system from caching the data.

PS: When I run the app on a different device, then it receives the current data. But when I again let it run on the original device - on which I observe this behaviour - then the data "received" is still outdated. So it really looks like some cashing issue to me.

Comment: I would advise against using `NSData` to perform network operations. It works, but there are much more idiomatic ways like `-[NSURLSession dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:]` or `+[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:]` if you really want to do a synchronous request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea. Try calling

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

For more granular control on cashing use `NSURLConnection` or `NSURLSession`.

Comment: I'll try that. In the meantime the device receives updated data. Let me see if I can recreate the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not make a change. It would have been a workaround only because I am loading much more data, lots of images etc, which I clearly want to be cached. Yes, aparently I'll have to switch over to NSURLConnection.

Comment: In the end NSURLRequest did to the trick. I did what I wanted to do anyway. Before downloading that file (using whatever) I check with a HEAD request if the file was updated since it was loaded last time. Aparently NSURLRequest HEAD seems to invalidate the related cache entry. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did try Mundi's suggestion, to try clearing the cache, but this didn't make any difference in my iPhone app.

So, I tried a trick which I use in my Angular webapps, and appended the current time (in ticks) to the URL I'm attempting to open, and that *did* work:

```
    NSString* originalURL = @"http://somewebservices/data/1234";

    NSString* newURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?t=%f", originalURL, 
          [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];

    NSLog(@"Loading data from: '%@'", newURL);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:newURL];
    if (url == nil)
        return false;

    NSError *error;
    NSData* urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
```

(Sigh.)

I'm getting too old for this stuff....